# Sum up values in a column using dialogflow

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am very new to dialogflow and wanted to calculate the sum of all values in a column(age). My data structure is below  and I tried basically to retrieve those values.

**Structure of my data**

[image]

---

Please help to sum up all the values in the age column.

```js
function detectage(agent){
    return admin.database().ref('data').child(agent.parameters.name).once('value').then((snapshot) => { 
      const value = snapshot.val();
      const age = value.Age; 
        if(value !== null){
            agent.add(`The  age value from database is ${age}`);
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogflow, itself, offers nothing that will sum the values for you. While you can do this in your fulfillment function, Dialogflow won't automatically do it.

Your function looks like it is pulling a single record from the Firebase Database, rather than iterating over all the children that are under the `data` node and summing the values from the `Age` property of each child node.

Code to do that might look something more like

```
function detectage(agent){
    return admin.database().ref('data').once('value')
      .then((snapshot) => {
        let age = 0;
        snapshot.forEach( childSnapshot -> {
          const value = childSnapshot.val();
          age += value.Age; 
        }); 
        if(age !== null){
            agent.add(`The total age from database is ${age}`);
        }
    });
  }
```